# interpreting unix time in the context of hours

Tags: javascript, node.js, unix, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am new to Javascript development and I recently came across the use case of UNIX time. I was wondering how I could use it for my purpose. My desired outcome is simple: get unix timestamp values from database, compare them to the current timestamp, if the difference between the current timestamp and a timestamp value from the database is **less than 72 hours** append the value to a new array.

Here is my current code:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var sql = `SELECT id, s3_location, s3_expiration FROM sounds`;
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;

      for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        console.log(Date.now())
        console.log(result[i].s3_expiration)
      }

      resolve(result);
    });
  });
```

s3_expiration returns the timestamp from the database and date.now is the present one. Here is some sample output from the logs:

```
1628174289
1628360565071
1628174294
1628360565071
1628176443
1628360565071
1628176454
1628360565071
1628176526
1628360565071
1628176561
1628360565071
1628176568
1628360565071
1628176578
1628360565071
1628881107
1628360565071
1628881164
1628360565071
1628281251
1628360565071
1628281258
1628360565071
1628281755
```

The one with the more digits is the value from date.now() while the shorter one is from the database. Let me know how I can accomplish my desired outcome. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `Date.now()` is in milliseconds , the other is in seconds from epoch. Multiply other by 1000 to then find difference with `Date.now()` and do math to calculate hours based on difference in milliseconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.now()` is returning milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970.
And the *shorter* one looks to be the same thing, but in seconds.

So here is how If would make the comparision:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var sql = `SELECT id, s3_location, s3_expiration FROM sounds`;
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let seventyTwoHours = 72 * 60 * 60;
    let nowInSec = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000);

    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].s3_expiration > nowInSec - seventyTwoHours) {
        console.log("The timestamp is less than 72 hours old");
      }

      console.log(Date.now());
      console.log(result[i].s3_expiration);
    }

    resolve(result);
  });
});
```